# a way to make modification for the cover of radio input font color when input checked without label

Tags: css

i made p tag and input type radio is in there

```
<p class="item-3">
  <input id="fid-1" type="radio" name="globalType">Hey
</p>
```

How can i make "Hey" red with out label?
i already tried this

```
.item-3 input[type="radio"]:checked + p.item-3
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/17175441 . You may also place the `Hey` inside a span tag and then target that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a span element, and contain the 'hey' within the span element. This will create an inline element that you can then target with CSS.

If you are using multiple, use a class. If single, just an ID is fine.

CSS:

```
.hey {
    color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p class="item-3">
  <input id="fid-1" type="radio" name="globalType"><span class='hey'>Hey</span>
</p>
```